# Receiving an npm error after running "npm run build" : npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, node-sass

I am having difficulty getting to the bottom of this npm error I am receiving after my npm run build script executes. The error in the terminal is as follows:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! vincent-site@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vincent-site@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 
There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vincentcastelli/.npm/_logs/2018-11-10T20_27_41_388Z-debug.
```

Not very descriptive. I am using the most recent npm version at the time of writing this (6.4.1) and the most recent node (11.1.0). I am also using Babel 7 with Webpack 4 for my compiling. I have tried a few things so far.

I have tried the following steps when using both the recent version of npm/node and older versions:

1. npm cache clean --force
2. delete node_modules by $ rm -rf node_modules folder
3. npm install

Still receiving the error.

My log output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v11.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~prebuild: vincent-site@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: vincent-site@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: PATH: /Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/vincentcastelli/Documents/02_Projects/vincent-site/node_modules/.bin:/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
9 verbose lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/vincentcastelli/Documents/02_Projects/vincent-site
10 silly lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack --mode production' ]
11 silly lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vincent-site@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: vincent-site@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:257:5)
14 verbose pkgid vincent-site@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/vincentcastelli/Documents/02_Projects/vincent-site
16 verbose Darwin 18.0.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/bin/node" "/Users/vincentcastelli/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v11.1.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error vincent-site@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the vincent-site@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

My package.json:

```
}
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-ejs": "0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const distDir = path.join(__dirname, '/dist');
const srcDir = path.join(__dirname, '/src');


module.exports = {
  entry: `${srcDir}/index.jsx`,
  output: {
    path: `${distDir}`,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader",
                "css-loader",
                "sass-loader"
            ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|mp4|ogv|webm)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./dist/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ],
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
};
```

I feel that the issue stems from a package versioning incompatibility but isolating the issue has been challenging. Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Comment: What did you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: $ npm cache clean --force

Step 2: delete node_modules folder

step 3: delete package-lock.json file

Step 4: npm install

To start again, $ npm run start or npm run build

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this did not work and I am receiving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I found out my CI/CD pipeline on Semaphore was running on a virtual machine without enough memory, thus it was failing and throwing me the error

Check your memory wherever you are running that command